# Understanding the asterisk operator in python when it's before the function in a parenthesis

Tags: python, asynchronous, syntax, python-asyncio, argument-unpacking

I know that the asterisk is used to unpack values like system args or when you unpack lists into variables.

But I have not seen this syntax here before in this example of asyncio.

I was reading this article here, https://realpython.com/async-io-python/#the-10000-foot-view-of-async-io , but I don't understand what the asterisk operator is doing in this context.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# rand.py

import asyncio
import random

# ANSI colors
c = (
    "\033[0m",   # End of color
    "\033[36m",  # Cyan
    "\033[91m",  # Red
    "\033[35m",  # Magenta
)

async def makerandom(idx: int, threshold: int = 6) -> int:
    print(c[idx + 1] + f"Initiated makerandom({idx}).")
    i = random.randint(0, 10)
    while i <= threshold:
        print(c[idx + 1] + f"makerandom({idx}) == {i} too low; retrying.")
        await asyncio.sleep(idx + 1)
        i = random.randint(0, 10)
    print(c[idx + 1] + f"---> Finished: makerandom({idx}) == {i}" + c[0])
    return i

async def main():
    res = await asyncio.gather(*(makerandom(i, 10 - i - 1) for i in range(3)))
    return res

if __name__ == "__main__":
    random.seed(444)
    r1, r2, r3 = asyncio.run(main())
    print()
    print(f"r1: {r1}, r2: {r2}, r3: {r3}")
```

Under the `async def main function` right before the `makerandom` there is an asterisk. Could someone explain what it does in this context ? I am trying to understand how async / await works.

I looked at this answer, [Python asterisk before function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382207/python-asterisk-before-function) but it doesn't really explain it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The asterisk isn't before `makerandom`, it's before the generator expression

```
(makerandom(i, 10 - i - 1) for i in range(3))
```

`asyncio.gather` doesn't take an iterable as its first argument; it accepts a variable number of awaitables as positional arguments. In order to get from a generator expression to that, you need to unpack the generator.

In this particular instance, the asterisk unpacks

```
asyncio.gather(*(makerandom(i, 10 - i - 1) for i in range(3)))
```

into

```
asyncio.gather(makerandom(0, 9), makerandom(1, 8), makerandom(2, 7))
```

Comment: Side note: you can also use the asterisk operator to unpack a list.

Answer (score 3):

An asterisk, means [unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/). It spreads the [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) into several [arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument) as in:

```py
array = [1, 2, 3]
print(*array)
```

would be the same as

```py
print(1, 2, 3)
```

Another example:

```py
generator = (x for x in range(10) if my_function(x))
print(*generator)
```

One asterisk is being used for ordinary iterables, but when it comes to [mappings](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-mapping), you can also use double-asterisk as `**` in order to unpack the mapping into keyword arguments, as in:

```py
dictionary = {"hello": 1, "world": 2}
my_function(**dictionary)
```

This would be equivalent to `my_function(hello=1, world=2)`.
You can also use the ordinary one-asterisk in order to only unpack the keys from the mapping:

```py
print(*{"hello": 1, "world": 2})
```

This would result in `hello world`